# Chromebook local network file access

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os, chromebook

What are the options I have to mount network file shares to a Chromebook running stock Chrome OS with developer mode?

I noticed `/proc/filesystems` doesn't contain `nfs` but it has `fuse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of poking around I figured this out (must have sshd running on the remote box):

[as chronos user]

```
cd ~/Downloads
sshfs user@192.168.1.1:remote_folder local_folder/
```

Change 'remote_folder' 'local_folder' to real folder names and the remote files in remote_folder should appear in the local Downloads/local_folder/ directory.

Then to unmount the remote directory:

```
fusermount -u tmp/
```

Easy peasy...

Comment: Did you have to install sshfs on the chromebook? After enabling developer mode and switching to the dev shell, I don't see sshfs installed by default. I know I can easily install it in a chroot (like crouton) but you specifically said "as chronos user" which makes me think there must be another way. Note this is a Pixel with developer mode enabled, but using the Stable channel. I wonder if more tools come with a Beta or Developer channel build?

Comment: @Sk606: You need to install the developer packages first: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/install-software-on-base-images

Answer (score 0):

Run LanFolder On Both Machines But It ***Only*** Runs On A Network ***Not*** Outside The Network That The Remote Box Is On And The Remote Box Has To Be **On**